# Import variations wp all import

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, import

i'm using WP All import to import product from my huge database, but unfortunately, the database isn't similar at the examples provided by the tutorial there are no parent product.
I have in the same CSV row unique SKU and attributes, in fact a list of variations.
Is it possible to make the import anyway?

Rows
Example row 1: SKUA01, productnameA, colorA, SizeB. Row 2: SKUA01, productnameA, colorG, SizeB.. and so on..

Comment: Can you provide an example row? It is definitely possible but I can't provide direction without seeing the format.

Comment: Example row 1: SKUA01, productnameA, colorA, SizeB. Row 2: SKUA01, productnameA, colorG, SizeB.. and so on..

Answer (score 0):

3 years later, but did you find your solution you are looking for? Why don't you upload it here to help others too?

I had a similar issue, but made some changes to CSV file, specially in attributes. I guess in your case can't do that, because of a huge DB like you said.

Thus, did you try to insert via same PRODUCT NAME. There is an option "**All variations for a particular product have the same title. There are no parent products.**".. All the rows have the same product name and there are no parent products. You need to pick `variable product` **not simple**

Moreover, inside "**Attribute**" panel you could add yours;

"**Name**": color
"**Values**" colorG (drug and drop your value from the right sidebar into the field)

Not tested, but  that's the thought